# Why gpg show different uids in --list-keys and --list-secret-keys?

Tags: linux, gnupg

I had add an new uid, and revoke an old one, using --edit-key command.

Here is my output (already replace email with "uidx"):

```
▶ gpg --list-keys; gpg --list-secret-keys 
/home/xxxx/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
-----------------------------
pub   2048R/A6573CCA 2012-07-26
uid                  uid1
uid                  uid2
uid                  uid3
uid                  uid4
uid                  [jpeg image of size 3757]
sub   2048R/88364032 2012-07-26

/home/xxxx/.gnupg/secring.gpg
-----------------------------
sec   2048R/A6573CCA 2012-07-26
uid                  An revoked uid5 here.
uid                  uid2
uid                  uid1
ssb   2048R/88364032 2012-07-26
```

Comment: What's `man gpg` say about the difference between the commands?

Comment: Did you by chance edit the key with GnuPG 2.1? This moved private keys into the public keyring, which might explain differences between the public and private key listings.